# Two dropdown with one with start date another with end date on power bi, also date will be text type

Tags: date, powerbi, dax, dropdown, slicers

On pbi want to show visual having dates between start date and end date but those dates are need to be of text type and only through dropdown slicer have to use.

I did tried with stopping edit interaction between  dropdown and visuals.
Then dax is not working

Comment: Why do they have to of type text? If that's really the case, you can have a calendar table with one column that's a real date and another that's text (like a formatted date). And then you can filter/sort based on the real date.